# Find/Filter all rows that contains an incorrect date format

Tags: python, pandas

I am analyzing some shared data sheets,I set some filters so that this helps to find rows that do not follow the criteria:

```
filter3 = df[(df['Currency'].isnull())]
filter1= df[(df["Date"] > '2021-06-16' ) & (df['Subtype'].isnull())]
```

However I have tried to put a filter so when running the script I can find rows that does not follow this date format: `%d/%m/%Y`

How can I implement this filter? At the end what I would like to do is inform to the person adding rows to that shared report that he/she typed the incorrect format.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use the `errors` parameter of `pd.to_datetime`.  If any of the date values don't adhere to the format it will return null.  In this case we use `.loc` to select the null (invalid) dates.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['2021-06-16','11/08/20']})
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], errors='coerce',format='%Y-%m-%d').isnull()]
```

Output

```
dates
1   11/08/20
```

Comment: Thank you Chris!